# Deriving components of a bra vector using orthonormal basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, inner-products, orthonormal

I'm stuck already in an introductory chapter about bras and kets. I included all of the context but I'm stuck at figure 1.5.

[image]

[image]

In figure 1.5, what does $\alpha_j$ mean? In the previous figures, the subscript $i$ only held meaning as the iterated integer of the summation.

I guess I should be able to imply what it's supposed to mean based on the preceding paragraph, but I'm stuck there too.

So then how that becomes the final figure (unnumbered) is beyond me.

If someone can perceive what might be confusing me and explain in a different manner, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The $j$ index relate the coefficient $\alpha$ with the $j$ vector. You can change $\langle j|A\rangle$ by $\langle e_j|A\rangle=\alpha_j$ where $e_j$ is a basis vector of the vector space, if you like and to make it easy to understand.